# Referring to built files in html using module bundlers

Tags: html, gulp, build-system

I'm using the Gulp to build my SCSS, Pug and ES6 assets for my static website. I know it's possible to hash file names and output the files in a different directory.

For my specific example:

- my Pug markdown are found in the `~/src/pages` directory and getting built to the `~/public/` directory.
- My SCSS stylesheets are found in the `~/src/stylesheets` directory. These are getting built to the  and getting `~/public/style` directory

My problem is, when I'm referring to my stylesheets files from Pug, I have to refer to the already-built folder like this:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='./style/example.css')
```

For my IDE, this doesn't make sense, because the `style` directory doesn't exist in the `~/src/pages` directory.

What I would find the most useful is that I can refer to my stylesheets like the example below:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='../stylesheets/example.scss')
```

Is there any way this is possible or am I completely going in the wrong direction? If not, where am I looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to make the file name like hash

- gulp, for automating our task
- [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev), for renaming our files with random hashes.
- [gulp-rev-collector](https://github.com/shonny-ua/gulp-rev-collector), for switching non-hashed references by hashed-references inside our files.
- [rev-del](https://github.com/callumacrae/rev-del), for deleting non-hashed files in our /dist folder.

Sample code :

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task("revision:rename", ["serve"], () =>
  gulp.src(["dist/**/*.html",
            "dist/**/*.css",
            "dist/**/*.js",
            "dist/**/*.{jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg}"])
  .pipe(rev())
  .pipe(revdel())
  .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"))
  .pipe(rev.manifest({ path: "manifest.json" }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"))
);
```

manifest.json

```
{
  style.css: style-ds9udjvci.css,
  main.js: main-dijds9xc9.min.js
}
```

For creating our revision update in the file like 
Rewrite every reference for every key of manifest.json to it’s respective value inside every html/json/css/js file `(i.e: <link href="style.css"> would become <link href="style-ds9udjvci.css">)`

```
gulp.task("revision:updateReferences", ["serve", "revision:rename"], () =>
  gulp.src(["dist/manifest.json","dist/**/*.{html,json,css,js}"])
 .pipe(collect())
 .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) for real-time compiling of your .scss files, then your `/style/example.css` file will exist and it will be recompiled automatically when you modify `example.scss`

You may need to move some directories around to get everything to link, but you can use watch to build your Pug files too, so your site will always be up to date.

Basically, you make a change on any file in your project and view the update live.

Answer (score 0):

Gulp cannot automatically change the file paths used inside the htmls. Therefore you will have to use the generated file path for accessing the style files.

Although if you want to have the file path as the folder structure of your scss, then you will have to replace the contents of the pug file after gulp has finished converting it to HTML.

You can convert the html to String and use the .replace method to replace whatever content you want to change and finally parse the string to a HTML document.

Hope this helps!!